# I am having trouble updating to laravel 7.0 due to package due to package problems, I think

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am not used to working with packages, so excuse me if my question is worded incorrectly.
I was tasked with updating to Laravel 7 and today, one of the packages I was waiting on to get updated finally received an update, but when I try to run `composer update` I get this error.

```
  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove askedio/laravel-soft-cascade 6.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install askedio/laravel-soft-cascade 6.0.1
    - Conclusion: don't install askedio/laravel-soft-cascade 6.0.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.3.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.2.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.1.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.1
    - Installation request for askedio/laravel-soft-cascade ^6.0 -> satisfiable by askedio/laravel-soft-cascade[6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v7.0.0
    - askedio/laravel-soft-cascade 6.0.x-dev requires illuminate/support ^6.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.10.1], illuminate/support[6.x-dev, v6.0.0, v6.0.1, v6.0.2, v6.0.3, v6.0.4, v6.1.0, v6.10.0, v6.11.0, v6.12.0, v6.13.0, v6.13.1, v6.14.0, v6.15.0, v6.15.1, v6.16.0, v6.17.0, v6.17.1, v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.18.3, v6.2.0, v6.3.0, v6.4.1, v6.5.0, v6.5.1, v6.5.2, v6.6.0, v6.6.1, v6.6.2, v6.7.0, v6.8.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v6.10.1].
    - don't install illuminate/support 6.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.0.4|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.1.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.10.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.11.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.12.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.13.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.14.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.15.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.16.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.17.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.18.3|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.2.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.3.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.4.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.5.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.1|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.6.2|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.7.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - don't install illuminate/support v6.8.0|don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.7, v7.0.8, v7.1.0, v7.1.1, v7.1.2, v7.1.3, v7.2.0, v7.2.1, v7.2.2, v7.3.0].
```

Is there something that I am missing? I have already ran `composer install` and tried removing packages, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: can you post your composer.json file

Answer (score 0):

The `askedio/laravel-soft-cascade 6.0.x-dev` package requires version 6.0 of Laravel

I had the same issue with the `nstapelbroek/culpa` package and had to remove it to make my upgrade work.

Answer (score -2):

do you have `composer install` first ?
or
your `composer` is updated ? or learn doc because due to security or trouble laravel can disable package ( script of the package can use ).

And if you not have laravel installed globally install it. don't use composer for copying project by dist.

I think is a problem by a commit of laravel or another. Because i'm workin in laravel 7 and i never get this error